# How to merge multiple (similar) columns into many rows and reduce memory usage?

Tags: r, reshape2

**MY DATA**
Is 90730 obs. of 639 variables. A (smaller) reproducible example is below:

```
structure(list(Match = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Standard = c("E", 
"E", "E", "E"), Athlete = c("AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA"), Team = c("ONE", "ONE", "ONE", "ONE"), Quarter = c("1_1", 
"1_1", "1_1", "1_1"), Position = c("Back", "Back", "Back", "Back"), Sample = 1:4, X = c(4.9244, 4.9242, 4.924, 4.9239), Y = c(-13.3858, -13.3866, 
-13.3873, -13.388), Match.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Standard.1 = c("E", 
"E", "E", "E"), Athlete.1 = c("BB", "BB", "BB", 
"BB"), Team.1 = c("ONE", "ONE", "ONE", "ONE"), Quarter.1 = c("1_1", 
"1_1", "1_1", "1_1"), Position.1 = c("Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward"), Sample.1 = 1:4, X.1 = c(-12.3725, -12.3566, -12.3398, 
-12.322), Y.1 = c(-15.9311, -15.926, -15.9205, -15.9146)), .Names = c("Match", 
"Standard", "Athlete", "Team", "Quarter", "Position", "Sample", 
"X", "Y", "Match.1", "Standard.1", "Athlete.1", "Team.1", "Quarter.1", 
"Position.1", "Sample.1", "X.1", "Y.1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

**MY IDEAL OUTPUT**
I wish to merge the multiple (similar) columns to a data.frame that contains only 9 columns `(c("Match", "Standard", "Athlete", "Team", "Quarter", "Position", "Sample", "X", "Y"))`
**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I have attempted melting via the `reshape2` package and code below:

```
mdata <- melt(df, id=c("Match","Standard","Athlete","Team","Quarter","Position","Sample","X","Y"))
```

An error is returned stating `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 218.0 Mb`
I have also tried using `grep` via the code below:

```
M1Compile <-  data.frame(Match=unlist(df[grep('^Match', names(df))]), 
                 Standard=unlist(df[grep('^Standard', names(df))]), 
                 Athlete=unlist(df[grep('^Athlete', names(df))]), 
                 Team=unlist(df[grep('^Team', names(df))]),
                 Quarter=unlist(df[grep('^Quarter', names(df))]),
                 Position=unlist(df[grep('^Position', names(df))]),
                 Sample=unlist(df[grep('^Sample', names(df))]),
                 X=unlist(df[grep('^X', names(df))]),
                 Y=unlist(df[grep('^Y', names(df))]),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
row.names(M1Compile) <- NULL<br><br>
```

However, I receive the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.0 Mb`
Any suggestions? I have saved `df` as a .RData file, reopened R with no success. I have also run `gc()` and closed all other background programs to assist with memory, again with no success.
**MY QUESTION**
Is there a better way to structure my data/ reduce memory and attain my ideal output, as per above?
**SESSION INFO**

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reshape2_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5  plyr_1.8.3    tools_3.2.2   Rcpp_0.12.2   stringi_1.0-1 
stringr_1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example data

```
dd <- structure(list(Match = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Standard = c("E",  "E", "E", "E"), Athlete = c("AA", "AA", "AA",  "AA"), Team = c("ONE", "ONE", "ONE", "ONE"), Quarter = c("1_1",  "1_1", "1_1", "1_1"), Position = c("Back", "Back", "Back", "Back"), Sample = 1:4, X = c(4.9244, 4.9242, 4.924, 4.9239), Y = c(-13.3858, -13.3866,  -13.3873, -13.388), Match.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Standard.1 = c("E",  "E", "E", "E"), Athlete.1 = c("BB", "BB", "BB",  "BB"), Team.1 = c("ONE", "ONE", "ONE", "ONE"), Quarter.1 = c("1_1",  "1_1", "1_1", "1_1"), Position.1 = c("Forward", "Forward", "Forward", "Forward"), Sample.1 = 1:4, X.1 = c(-12.3725, -12.3566, -12.3398,  -12.322), Y.1 = c(-15.9311, -15.926, -15.9205, -15.9146)), .Names = c("Match",  "Standard", "Athlete", "Team", "Quarter", "Position", "Sample",  "X", "Y", "Match.1", "Standard.1", "Athlete.1", "Team.1", "Quarter.1",  "Position.1", "Sample.1", "X.1", "Y.1"), row.names = c(NA, 4L ), class = "data.frame")


dd <- dd[rep_len(seq.int(nrow(dd)), 90000), ]

system.time({
  tmp <- reshape(dd, dir = 'l', varying = as.list(data.frame(t(matrix(1:18, ncol = 2)))))
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.144   0.014   0.158 

dim(tmp)
# [1] 180000     11


head(tmp)
#     time Match Standard Athlete Team Quarter Position Sample      X        Y id
# 1.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      1 4.9244 -13.3858  1
# 2.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      2 4.9242 -13.3866  2
# 3.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      3 4.9240 -13.3873  3
# 4.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      4 4.9239 -13.3880  4
# 5.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      1 4.9244 -13.3858  5
# 6.1    1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      2 4.9242 -13.3866  6
```

For your 90,000 x 600 data, you might want to use something more efficient

```
dd <- dd[, rep(1:18, 10)]
dim(dd)
# [1] 90000   630

system.time({
  library('data.table')
  setDT(dd)
  dd <- melt(dd, id.vars = NULL, measure = patterns(names(dd)[1:9]),
             value.name = names(dd)[1:9])
})
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.070   0.031   0.101 

dim(dd)
# [1] 1800000      10


#          variable Match Standard Athlete Team Quarter Position Sample        X        Y
#       1:        1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      1   4.9244 -13.3858
#       2:        1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      2   4.9242 -13.3866
#       3:        1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      3   4.9240 -13.3873
#       4:        1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      4   4.9239 -13.3880
#       5:        1     1        E      AA  ONE     1_1     Back      1   4.9244 -13.3858
#       ---                                                                               
# 1799996:       20     1        E      BB  ONE     1_1  Forward      4 -12.3220 -15.9146
# 1799997:       20     1        E      BB  ONE     1_1  Forward      1 -12.3725 -15.9311
# 1799998:       20     1        E      BB  ONE     1_1  Forward      2 -12.3566 -15.9260
# 1799999:       20     1        E      BB  ONE     1_1  Forward      3 -12.3398 -15.9205
# 1800000:       20     1        E      BB  ONE     1_1  Forward      4 -12.3220 -15.9146
```